# Edit Mode: Does a "reset phong-shading" function (or add-on) exist?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, edit-mode, lighting

After doing a lot of vertex welding & knife cuts on my geometry to get the shape I want, the "Smooth Shading" isn't so smooth anymore. Anyone know of a way to reset the shading on the faces en masse, so they appear as newly created faces?

I mean, without having to first delete all the faces & then rebuilding them, vertex by vertex? This solution is quite time consuming on anything but a very simple object.

I'm assuming the phong-shading gets confused after I've heavily modified the inital vertex constellations, but I'm no programmer so I wouldn't know for sure.

Auto-rebuilding the topology isn't an option, since parts of the mesh are quite exact, for animation purposes...

[image: Visual example:]

Edit:
Solved. Mr. Broady's answer made me focus in on normals as the issue & didn't take long to find that Blender's got it covered from the "Mesh" menu:

[image: Fix:]

Comment: You can use data transfer modifier to copy normals from a high poly version of the mesh, but it's typically used for hard surface modelling - for characters you probably want to keep a quad-based topology (and for this exact reason, correct smooth shading).

Comment: Aah, it was quad topology all along! I missed that.